# Set text and color for markers using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, openlayers

I want to set a text and color for each marker with JSON data when I append them to map. This example code is fine. Text and color are static at the moment. Can I do it with some function or maybe should I change the syntax to make it work?

```
const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 18,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [0, 155, 0, 0.6]
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: [0, 200, 0, 0.9],
        width: 3
      })
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      text: "Test",
      scale: 1.2,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: "#fff"
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "0",
        width: 3
      })
    })
  })
})
vectorLayer.setZIndex(5);
const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    ),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  target: "map",
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
     zoom: 5
  })
});
const addMarkers = (lat, long) => {
  if(lat && lat !== 0) {
    const point = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lat, long], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"));
    const iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
      geometry: point
    });
    vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
  }
}
// Positions come from map.jade
positions.forEach(position => {
  let long = position.geolocation.longitude;
  let lat = position.geolocation.latitude;
  if (long !== 0 && long !== 999.9 && long !== "" &&  long !== undefined) {
    addMarkers(long, lat);  
  }
});
```

Comment: If you need dynamic style for every point you need to move generation of your style in addMarkers so it can be done each time it's called. There has to be some call to API to get JSON each time and you have to vait for success and then make marker. If you store JSON locally then you need a mechanism how to read local data into JSON. NodeJS is one viable solution then with it's require. You also need some mechanism to know which point uses which JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ol.layer.Vector constructor, instead of passing an ol.style.Style instance, you can pass a function.

That function will receive feature and resolution and shall return an ol.style.Style object.

Here's an example: http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch06-styling-vector-layers/example-07.html

Otherwise, you can use the ol.Feature.setStyle function inside the addMarkers function.